# No provider for service - Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-services

I've created a **Singleton** service in Angular which does API calls before the application starts. It works on the first loaded page but if I navigate to another page it says:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyComponent -> MyService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyComponent -> MyService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for MyService!

I have no clue right now why, because this service is injected into both components, and works for the first one.

My `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
        MyService, {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (myService: MyService) => function () { return myService.load() },
            deps: [MyService],
            multi: true
        }]
```

My `my.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
...
}
```

The import in both components:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
```

Can someone please guide me how to fix this?

Comment: Is the other page in the same module?

Comment: Yes, everything is in one module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried replicating your problem, but it is working for me.
Please check this code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-palz6c

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER  } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { MyServiceService } from './my-service.service';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, TestComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [MyServiceService, {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (myService: MyServiceService) => function () { return myService.load() },
            deps: [MyServiceService],
            multi: true
        }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceService {

  constructor() { }

  load() {

        // return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        //     console.log("AppInitService.init() called");
        //     ////do your initialisation stuff here  
        //     setTimeout(() => {
        //         console.log('AppInitService Finished');
        //         resolve();
        //     }, 6000);

        // });
        console.log('AppInitService Finished');
    }

    test(val){
      console.log('test' + '-' + val);
    }
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyServiceService } from '../my-service.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: MyServiceService) { 
    console.log(this.service.test('Test Component'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Exactly the same, except that I'm using the service in app.component.ts as well, but shouldn't be causing it.

Comment: I've tested it with 3 components and 2 worked, one did not. The only difference was that the correct two used "absolute" path while the bad one was like "../../services/". Weird. Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to `my.service.ts:`

```
@Injectable({providedin 'root'})
```

Comment: That would make my service non-singleton.

Comment: @Peter that's how you declare a service as a singleton. I don't think this will fix your issue, but it's the recommended approach because it supports tree shaking.

Comment: If I add provided in root my constructor runs multiple times.

Comment: There is a common Subject for which multiple components should be able to subscribe on, therefore I need one instance.

Comment: @Peter once you have it provided in root, then remove it from being provided in modules.

Comment: This is the catch 22, then my app initialization block won't run before everything else. :(